Is there any way to get a list of retiring azure services programmically?
I have to write a function to log tickets in jira for retired services.
Is there any api or rs feed for the following?
Retiring Azure Services
Any help in retrieving the list will be appreciated.
I have had a look at resource Graph using a query, but have very limited success as I am relatively new to resource graphs.

Can you try below in Azure Resource Graph Explorer
ServiceHealthResources
| where type =~ 'Microsoft.ResourceHealth/events'
| extend type = properties.EventSubType , eventType = properties.EventType, status = properties.Status, description = properties.Title, trackingId = properties.TrackingId, summary = properties.Summary, priority = properties.Priority, startTime = todatetime(tolong(properties.ImpactStartTime)), lastUpdate = todatetime(tolong(properties.LastUpdateTime))
| where type contains 'Retire'

